# How to name a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, alias

My professor is asking for me to include a query name for each and every query that is involved with this homework. I'm assuming he's referring to an alias, so I've used this code successfully with some questions:

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) AS Problem1
FROM Customers;
```

However, I can't us AS when creating tables or deleting columns like this (without an error).

```
CREATE TABLE TestDB AS Problem6
(
SuggestionID Char(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Suggestion VarChar(100) NOT NULL,
SugContact Char(30) NOT NULL,
SugPhone Char(10),
SugDate Date NOT NULL,
SugPriority INT
)
```

OR when using INSERT INTO. So my question is this: how do I name a specific query, specifically when creating a database like the above or when deleting a column.

Comment: The `AS Problem1` doesn't name the query, it names the column.  If you were selecting multiple columns, each would have its own name.  You need to ask your professor what he wants.

Comment: --Problem1 comes to mind

Comment: How do you have to submit this? Maybe you're thinking too much into it and he just wants you to give each one a name on submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to name a query as such - you could put it into a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) or alternatively - and more likely, he'll just want you to label the query with a comment like so:

```
-- Question 1
CREATE TABLE TestDB( ...
```

Comment: You're probably right about the comment thing. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use with, so for example:

```
WITH Problem_1 AS (
 SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) as Customers
 from Customer
 )
```

in your example the when you use as you are just changing the column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
(SELECT * AS B FROM TBL1)A
```

`A` is name of the above query.

You can use `A` Like this:

```
SELECT PID 
FROM 
    (SELECT ProductID AS PID, ProductName AS PNAME 
     FROM Products 
     WHERE ProductID = 32) A
```

A real example:

```
SELECT 
    cID AS `Customer ID`,
    cNM AS `Customer Name`,
    MAX(SumPrice) AS `Total order `
FROM
    (SELECT 
         Customers.CustomerID AS cID, 
         Customers.CustomerName AS cNM,  
         SUM(Products.Price * OrderDetails.Quantity) AS SumPrice
     FROM
         (((Orders
     INNER JOIN 
         Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
     INNER JOIN 
         OrderDetails ON OrderDetails.OrderID = orders.OrderID)
     INNER JOIN 
         Products ON OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID)
     GROUP BY 
         CustomerName) A
```

We used result of `A` query

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uUbb.png)